# Function messed up?

Tags: python

Why is this function not working? It seems n is never equal to 2.

```
def Option2():
    n = random.randrange(2)
    if n==2:
        print ("You find a mysterious black box and you hear noises coming from within it.")
        print ("What do you do?")
        print ("1. Open it.")
        print ("2. Investigate the enviroment surrouding it.")
        print ("3. Smell it begrudgingly.")
```

Answer (score 7):

`random.randrange()` works just like the built-in `range()`; the *end value is not included*. `random.randrange(2)` only ever produces `0` or `1`.

From the [`random.randrange()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange):

> This is equivalent to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`, but doesn’t actually build a range object.

and `range(2)` produces:

```
>>> range(2)
[0, 1]
```

Comment: So n would have to equal either 0 or 1 in order for it to work?

Comment: @Camil yes, or use `randrange(3)`.